# PHP code for language detection doesn't work on WAMP server 2

Tags: php, detection

I'm using `$lang=$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];` to detect the language of the browser. At first, I thought something was wrong with my code. But then I tried [this demo](http://urbanoalvarez.es/lang/test.php), and even if I had my 'display preferred language' as Spanish (es), it displayed the content in English (en). Finally, I figured out that it doesn't work in localhost (Using [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server 2), but it does online.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser doesn't send an `Accept-Language:` request header, the PHP default is `en`.

Fix for Firefox: Type `about:config` in the address bar. Then change the following entries:

```
general.useragent.locale
intl.accept_languages
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1333) Firefox add-on to see if it helps you change your locale in your test environment.